# Java/Jsoup - HTML element's ID changes with each refesh

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have a piece of code that I am using to scrape data from various websites using the Jsoup library.

```
Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(url);
try {
    doc = conn.get();
    Element element = doc.getElementById(elementId);
    System.out.println(element.html());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code works fine for most websites, however I have noticed that for one of the websites I am scraping from, this code does not work because the id for the HTML element of interest changes with each refresh of the page, by what appears to be the appending of a random number to the end of the id.

Is this done purposefully to prevent people from scraping data? If so, what is the best way (if any) of getting around it?

Comment: Not sure why is it done. Perhaps you could try selecting the element not using the id? http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax might give you some clues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: **You should not scrape websites that did not give consent to your doing.**

If you are feel that your scraping is legit, I would look for things in the html code that keep stable. It is not necessarily the id. class names are very often used in a similar and distinctive way.

In your described case, it sounds as if the base name of the id keeps stable. So you could do this:

```
Element element = doc.select(*[id^=baseID]).first();
```

This will select the first Element which has an id attribute that starts with "baseID". Look for [CSS selectors in JSoup](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion seems to have worked. How do I know if my scraping is legit? I'm not making any kind of commercial software. I just assumed that there wasn't any problem with scraping publicly available data.

Comment: Well, you could ask the website owner if your kind of access is okay for a non-commercial/private project. Of course you can also decide to not ask - the data IS public, you are right. But what if your scraper puts a lot of web-traffic on the site in question? This may make the site hard to access for others... If you don't ask, at least behave in a way that would be tolerable if you put yourself in the website owners position and think about it.